# How to integrate SnappyData with Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, snappydata

For enterprise usage, we need to integrate Kerberos for SnappyData. Do you have any documentation for doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SnappyData Enterprise supports LDAP for authentication but we now in the midst of adding support for kubernetes (coming in GA form soon) which will our primary mechanism to support a wide range of security options including using tickets(kerberos).

What security provider do you use for kerberos ?